# jQuery white box appearing only on Safari

Tags: jquery, html

A horizontal white box appears the width of the browser page between jQuery div only on initial load (between first "palm tree" pic and second "arrow" pic). I'm using a parallax style effect that might have something to do with it. Issue only seen when using Safari and not in any other browser. The box disappears after window resize or scroll. Thanks in advance!

Site:
www.fullblownedit.com

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>fullblownedit \\</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
body,td,th {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ? true : false;
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ? true : false;
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) ? true : false;
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) ? true : false;
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

if (isMobile.any()) {
    window.location = 'http://www.fullblownedit.com/mobile.html';
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav').localScroll(800);
    $('#nav_badge').localScroll(800);


    $('#intro').parallax("50%", 0.1);
    $('#second').parallax("50%", 0.1);
    $('.bg').parallax("50%", 0.4);
    $('#third').parallax("50%", 0.3);

})

</script>

</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
 <li><a href="#intro" title=""><img src="images/dot.png" alt="Link" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#second" title=""><img src="images/dot.png" alt="Link" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#third" title=""><img src="images/dot.png" alt="Link" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#fifth" title=""><img src="images/dot.png" alt="Link" /></a></li>
    </ul>



<div id="intro">
        <div class="story">


   <div align="center"><img src="images/logo.png" width="90" height="115"></div>

          </div>
</div>
</div>
    </div>

    <div id="second">
        <div class="story">
          <div class="bg"> </div>
          <div class="float-right">

            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>

              <div align="center"><img src="images/set.png" width="120" height="120">

              </div>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h1 align="center">

            <h1 align="left"><font color="#16a6b6"><font size="7"><strong>EDIT ANYWHERE.</strong></font></h1>
                <p align="left"><font color="#16a6b6">Whether we need to drop in and edit from our mobile edit bay, collaborate remotely, or travel to set during a production. We'll be a creative force ready to go wherever necessary.</font></p>



      </div>
</div>

    </div>

    <div id="third">
        <div class="story">
            <div class="float-left">

<h1 align="left"><font color="#ffffff"><font size="7"><strong>CONNECT</strong></font></h1>

<p><font size="8" face="Helvetica Light, Helvetica, Arial">hello@fullblownedit.com</font></p>

<p><font size="7"face="Helvetica Light, Helvetica, Arial">(949) 424-3348</font></p>

           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="fifth">
      <div class="story">

       <h1 align="center">
<h1 align="center"><font color="#000000"><font size="7"><strong>WATCH</strong></font></h1>
       <p align="center"><img src="images/sm_arrow.png" width="30" height="87"></p>
            <center>
        <iframe allowfullscreen="yes" frameborder="0" height="3820" width="900" src="fbe_watch.html"></iframe>


<ul id="nav_badge">
   <div align="center"><a href="#intro" title=""><img src="images/badge.png" width="115" height="117"></a></div>
    </ul>


<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>

      </div> 
</div> 

                    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*
Plugin: jQuery Parallax
Version 1.1.3
Author: Ian Lunn
Twitter: @IanLunn
Author URL: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/
Plugin URL: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/


@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 980px;
    padding: 0;
}

p{
    margin: 0 0 20px 0; 
}

p, ul{
    font-family:Avenir Next, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size-adjust:0.488;
    font-weight:200;
    font-style:normal;
}

img{
    border: 0;
}


h1, #pixels{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, serif;
    font-size-adjust:0.40;
    font-weight:700;
    font-style:normal;
}

h2{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size-adjust:0.531;
    font-weight:500;
    font-style:normal;
}

.float-left{
    float: left;    
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.float-right{
    float: right;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.center{
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 80px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav{
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 25px;
    top: 10px;
}

#nav li{
    margin: 0 0 15px 0; 
}


#header, #intro, #second{
    width: 100%;
}

#intro{
    background:url(images/firstBG.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 665px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#second{
    background: url(images/secondBG.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

#second .bg{
    background: url(images/trainers.png) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    height: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 900px;
    z-index: 200;
}

#third{
    background: url(images/thirdBG.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 565px;
    padding: 100px 0 0 0;   
}

#fifth{

    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.story{
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 980px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 980px;
}

.story .float-left{
    padding: 100px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;   
}
.story .float-right{
    padding: 100px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;   
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Anyone? Problem still exists. Any useful info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in Chrome also on load, can you try overflow:hidden, or try reset css, 
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thanks for the help Alex. No luck with the reset unfortunately. I tried overflow:hidden and no improvement either. Maybe I put it in the wrong line of code. Where would you put it?

Comment: I'm still seeing the white box. It's tough to test because once the site is cached a refresh will sometimes remove the box temporarily. However, if you empty website cache it's a true test as if a first time site visit is loading the page properly. The box shows up in that case. Any other thoughts?

Comment: yes, but in your example it dont move until its refreshed or scrolled.. in my example it remove it automatical on load, it sux but .. im 80% shure problem is with this <div id="second" style="background-position: 50% 67px;">   - if you put background color to that div you will see its from that div empty space... hope it helps

Comment: I appreciate the help but the white bar still shows with your example on load. It unfortunately does not automatically remove it after testing on both my home and work computer. I think you're right about the <div id="second"... being the issue though.